# How can I handle multiple messages concurrently from a JMS topic (not queue) with java and spring 3.0?

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, jms, messaging

Note that I'd like multiple message listeners to handle successive messages from the topic concurrently.  In addition I'd like each message listener to operate transactionally so that a processing failure in a given message listener would result in that listener's message remaining on the topic.

The spring DefaultMessageListenerContainer seems to support concurrency for JMS queues only.

Do I need to instantiate multiple DefaultMessageListenerContainers?

If time flows down the vertical axis:

```
ListenerA reads msg 1        ListenerB reads msg 2        ListenerC reads msg 3
ListenerA reads msg 4        ListenerB reads msg 5        ListenerC reads msg 6
ListenerA reads msg 7        ListenerB reads msg 8        ListenerC reads msg 9
ListenerA reads msg 10       ListenerB reads msg 11       ListenerC reads msg 12
...
```

**UPDATE:**
*Thanks for your feedback @T.Rob and @skaffman.*

What I ended up doing is creating multiple `DefaultMessageListenerContainers` with `concurrency=1` and then putting logic in the message listener so that only one thread would process a given message id.

Comment: Could you clarify? When I see "multiple message listeners to handle successive messages from the topic concurrently" I think it means you do not want the listeners to each get a copy of the same message but rather to compete for messages against each other on the same topic.  Is that correct?

Comment: This looks useful: http://bsnyderblog.blogspot.com/2010/05/tuning-jms-message-consumption-in.html

Answer (score 10):

You don't want multiple `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` instances, no, but you do need to configure the `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` to be concurrent, using the [`concurrentConsumers` property](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html#setConcurrentConsumers%28int%29):

> Specify the number of concurrent
>   consumers to create. Default is 1.
>
> Specifying a higher value for this
>   setting will increase the standard
>   level of scheduled concurrent
>   consumers at runtime: This is
>   effectively the minimum number of
>   concurrent consumers which will be
>   scheduled at any given time. This is a
>   static setting; for dynamic scaling,
>   consider specifying the
>   "maxConcurrentConsumers" setting
>   instead.
>
> Raising the number of concurrent
>   consumers is recommendable in order to
>   scale the consumption of messages
>   coming in from a queue. However, note
>   that any ordering guarantees are lost
>   once multiple consumers are
>   registered. In general, stick with 1
>   consumer for low-volume queues.

However, there's big warning at the bottom:

> **Do not raise the number of concurrent consumers for a topic**. 
>   This would lead to concurrent
>   consumption of the same message, which
>   is hardly ever desirable.

This is interesting, and makes sense when you think about it. The same would occur if you had multiple `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` instances.

I think perhaps you need to rethink your design, although I'm not sure what I'd suggest. Concurrent consumption of pub/sub messages seems like a perfectly reasonable thing to do, but how to avoid getting the same message delivered to all of your consumers at the same time?

Answer (score 3):

At least in ActiveMQ what you want is totally supported, his name is [VirtualTopic](http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html)

The concept is:

1. You create a **VirtualTopic** (Simply creating a Topic using the prefix `VirtualTopic.` ) eg. `VirtualTopic.Color`
2. Create a consumer subscribing to this **VirtualTopic** matching this pattern `Consumer.<clientName>.VirtualTopic.<topicName>` eg. `Consumer.client1.VirtualTopic.Color`, doing it, Activemq **will create a queue** with that name and that queue will subscribe to `VirtualTopic.Color` then every message published to this Virtual Topic will be delivered to **client1** queue, note that it works like rabbitmq exchanges.
3. You are done, now you can consume **client1** queue like every queue, with many consumers, DLQ, customized redelivery policy, etc.
4. At this point I think you understood that you can create **client2**, **client3** and how many **subscribers**  you want, all of them will receive a copy of the message published to `VirtualTopic.Color`

Here the code

```
@Component
public class ColorReceiver {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MailReceiver.class);

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    // simply generating data to the topic
    long id=0;
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 500)
    public void postMail() throws JMSException, IOException {

        final Color colorName = new Color[]{Color.BLUE, Color.RED, Color.WHITE}[new Random().nextInt(3)];
        final Color color = new Color(++id, colorName.getName());
        final ActiveMQObjectMessage message = new ActiveMQObjectMessage();
        message.setObject(color);
        message.setProperty("color", color.getName());
        LOGGER.info("status=color-post, color={}", color);
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(new ActiveMQTopic("VirtualTopic.color"), message);
    }

    /**
     * Listen all colors messages
     */
    @JmsListener(
        destination = "Consumer.client1.VirtualTopic.color", containerFactory = "colorContainer"
        selector = "color <> 'RED'"
    )
    public void genericReceiveMessage(Color color) throws InterruptedException {
        LOGGER.info("status=GEN-color-receiver, color={}", color);
    }

    /**
     * Listen only red colors messages
     *
     * the destination ClientId have not necessary exists (it means that his name can be a fancy name), the unique requirement is that
     * the containers clientId need to be different between each other
     */
    @JmsListener(
//      destination = "Consumer.redColorContainer.VirtualTopic.color",
        destination = "Consumer.client1.VirtualTopic.color",
        containerFactory = "redColorContainer", selector = "color='RED'"
    )
    public void receiveMessage(ObjectMessage message) throws InterruptedException, JMSException {
        LOGGER.info("status=RED-color-receiver, color={}", message.getObject());
    }

    /**
     * Listen all colors messages
     */
    @JmsListener(
        destination = "Consumer.client2.VirtualTopic.color", containerFactory = "colorContainer"
    )
    public void genericReceiveMessage2(Color color) throws InterruptedException {
        LOGGER.info("status=GEN-color-receiver-2, color={}", color);
    }

}

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
@EnableScheduling
@Configuration
public class Config {

    /**
     * Each @JmsListener declaration need a different containerFactory because ActiveMQ requires different
     * clientIds per consumer pool (as two @JmsListener above, or two application instances)
     * 
     */
    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> colorContainer(ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory, 
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {

        final DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        factory.setConcurrency("1-5");
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        // container.setClientId("aId..."); lets spring generate a random ID
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> redColorContainer(ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {

        // necessary when post serializable objects (you can set it at application.properties)
        connectionFactory.setTrustedPackages(Arrays.asList(Color.class.getPackage().getName()));

        final DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        factory.setConcurrency("1-2");
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        return factory;
    }

}

public class Color implements Serializable {

    public static final Color WHITE = new Color("WHITE");
    public static final Color BLUE = new Color("BLUE");
    public static final Color RED = new Color("RED");

    private String name;
    private long id;

    // CONSTRUCTORS, GETTERS AND SETTERS
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Creating a custom task executor seemingly solved the issue for me, w/o duplicate processing:

```
@Configuration
class BeanConfig {
    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor topicExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setAllowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);
        executor.setKeepAliveSeconds(300);
        executor.setCorePoolSize(4);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(0);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("TOPIC-");
        return executor;
    }

    @Bean
    JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> topicListenerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer, @Qualifier("topicExecutor") Executor topicExecutor) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setPubSubDomain(true);
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        factory.setPubSubDomain(true);
        factory.setSessionTransacted(false);
        factory.setSubscriptionDurable(false);
        factory.setTaskExecutor(topicExecutor);
        return factory;
    }

}

class MyBean {
    @JmsListener(destination = "MYTOPIC", containerFactory = "topicListenerFactory", concurrency = "1")
    public void receiveTopicMessage(SomeTopicMessage message) {}
}
```

Comment: if `concurrency` is set to 1 then how does use of `topicExecutor` helps?

Answer (score 2):

Multiple Consumers Allowed on the Same Topic Subscription in JMS 2.0, while this was not the case with JMS 1.1. Please refer:
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jms2messaging-1954190.html

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those occasions where the differences in transport providers bubble up through the abstraction of JMS.  JMS wants to provide a copy of the message for each subscriber on a topic.  But the behavior that you want is really that of a queue.  I suspect that there are other requirements driving this to a pub/sub solution which were not described - for example other things need to subscribe to the same topic independent of your app.

If I were to do this in WebSphere MQ the solution would be to create an administrative subscription which would result in a single copy of each message on the given topic to be placed onto a queue.  Then your multiple subscribers could compete for messages on that queue.  This way your app could have multiple threads among which the messages are distributed, and at the same time other subscribers independent of this application could dynamically (un)subscribe to the same topic.

Unfortunately, there's no generic JMS-portable way of doing this.  You are dependent on the transport provider's implementation to a great degree.  The only one of these I can speak to is WebSphere MQ but I'm sure other transports support this in one way or another and to varying degrees if you are creative.

Comment: I like your idea. I guess that we can implement it w/o tying to a specific provider. We create a topic and only one subscriber for it. That subscriber puts the message from the topic into a queue and now multiple queue consumers can compete for it. It adds a level of indirection, but solves the problem of concurrency for topic in DMLC.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possibility:

1) create only one DMLC configured with the bean and method to handle the incoming message. Set its concurrency to 1.

2) Configure a task executor with its #threads equal to the concurrency you desire. Create an object pool for objects which are actually supposed to process a message. Give a reference of task executor and object pool to the bean you configured in #1. Object pool is useful if the actual message processing bean is not thread-safe.

3) For an incoming message, the bean in DMLC creates a custom Runnable, points it to the message and the object pool, and gives it to task executor.

4) The run method of Runnable gets a bean from the object pool and calls its 'process' method with the message given.

#4 can be managed with a proxy and the object pool to make it easier.

I haven't tried this solution yet, but it seems to fit the bill. Note that this solution is not as robust as EJB MDB. Spring e.g. will not discard an object from the pool if it throws a RuntimeException.

Comment: How do you ensure the incoming JMS messages are not ack'd until the Runnable completes successfully?

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same problem. I'm currently investigating RabbitMQ, which seems to offer a perfect solution in a design pattern they call "work queues." More info here: http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-java.html

If you're not totally tied to JMS you might look into this. There might also be a JMS to AMQP bridge, but that might start to look hacky.

I'm having some fun (read: difficulties) getting RabbitMQ installed and running on my Mac but think I'm close to having it working, I will post back if I'm able to solve this.

Comment: Tried it and RabbitMQ works like a charm. It's not JMS, but I'm using Spring and the Rabbit/AMQP support is good enough for me.

Comment: Anyway in my experience rabbitmq has problems to lose messages in a clusterized ecosystem

Answer (score 0):

on server.xml configs:

so , in maxSessions you can identify the number of sessions you want.

Answer (score -2):

Came across this question. My configuration is :

Create a bean with `id="DefaultListenerContainer"`, add property `name="concurrentConsumers" value="10"` and property `name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value ="50"`.

Works fine, so far. I printed the thread id and verified that multiple threads do get created and also reused.

Comment: Check the warning that skaffman mentioned in his answer above.

Comment: This answer contained a promise to add performance tests, but that never quite got added! I've removed that text, but if you would like to add this at some point, do feel free.