# Multithreaded JMS receiving in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jms

I'm trying to write a multithreaded implementation for JMS message processing from a queue.

I've tried with DefaultMessageListenerContainer and SimpleMessageListenerContainer classes.

The problem I have is that it seems like just a single instance of the MessageListener class gets ever instantiated, no matter how I configure it. This forces me to unnecessarily write stateless or thread-safe MessageListener implementations, since I have the ListenerContainer configured to use multiple threads (concurrentConsumers=8).

Is there an obvious solution to this that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is by design. The `MessageListener` is a dependency that you inject into Spring - it has no way of instantiating new ones.

> This forces me to unnecessarily write stateless or thread-safe messageListener implementations

You make that sound like a bad thing. Making your `MessageListener` is a very good idea, Spring just removes the temptation to do otherwise.

Comment: I don't understand. I am making my MessageListener. I just want it to take advantage of my machine's multi-cores to process things in parallel.

Comment: @Iker: Yes, and the MessageListenerContainer will spawn multiple threads to do this, with all threads using the same instance of your `MessageListener`. Spawning multiple listeners is inefficient and unnecessary.

Comment: Ok, that I understand. But lets say that for each JMS message you have to process a job that takes a few seconds. I want to be able to use a completely separate set of instances to process each of the messages. Should I spawn threads from the MessageListener then?

Comment: @Iker: You can do that if you choose, yes.

Comment: If you're going to do that, you may consider implementing your 'process' as a prototype scoped bean in spring and lookup that bean via your MDP.  In this way you'll get a new instance of the java bean doing the actual processing.

Comment: @skaffman Should I shutdown the executor in the overridden onMessage method event? That is where I execute the ExecutorService. And I am really not sure if I should ever shutdown the executor at all as there will always be incoming messages. Doing `shutdown()` will reject the incomming tasks too which is not I want to happen. I want to constantly process messages received asynchronously using threads.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this answer is too late, but it may benefit others who're searching for it. In short, the answer is using `CommonsPoolTargetSource` and `ProxyFactoryBean`.

Check out this link for details: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?34595-MDB-vs-MDP-concurrency

If you want to do something similar for *topic*, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12668538/266103

Answer (score 1):

Configuring "concurrentConsumers" is just enough to process messages concurrently. This doesn't mean you will have "n" instances of MessageListenerContainer. The MessageListenerContainer may span "tasks" internally to process the messages. Optionally, you may have to configure your logging accordingly to see the information associated with the underlying tasks/threads.

See "[Tuning JMS message consumption in Spring](http://bsnyderblog.blogspot.com/2010/05/tuning-jms-message-consumption-in.html)" for more details.