# ActiveMQ - Java - How to receive multiple messages at once?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, activemq-classic, messagebroker

Hi I have successfully set up a message listener using the code below:

MessageSubscriber.java

```
public class MessageSubscriber {

  @Autowired
  MessageReceiver callback;

  public void subscribe(String topicName) throws JMSException {
    final ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
        MqHelper.createActiveMQConnectionFactory(activeMQEndpoint,
            activeMQUsername, activeMQPassword);

    receiveMessage(connectionFactory, topicName);
  }

  private void receiveMessage(ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory, String topicName)
      throws JMSException {
    final Connection consumerConnection = connectionFactory.createConnection();

    final Session consumerSession =
        consumerConnection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

    final Destination consumerDestination = consumerSession.createTopic(topicName);

    final MessageConsumer consumer = consumerSession.createConsumer(consumerDestination);

    consumer.setMessageListener(callback);

    consumerConnection.start();
  }
}
```

MessageReceiver.java

```
public class MessageReceiver implements MessageListener {

  private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageReceiver.class);

  @Override
  public void onMessage(Message message) {
    logger.info("Receiving message!");
    // ... I handle the message here
  }
}
```

When I handle the message I use a service where I have to fetch the result a short while later. This usually takes around 30-40 seconds. This isn't an issue, the issue is that only one message is being handled at a time.

For example, when 5 messages are published to a topic, 1 message will come in and I see the "Receiving message!" log and 30-40 seconds will go by until it gets the response. Only at that point when the processing is done do I see the next "Receiving message!" log. This means 5 messages will take roughly 3 minutes rather than less than 1 minute.

Edit: I should say that I am using spring boot, hence why the MessageReceiver is autowired. This means it is essentially a singleton, could this be the problem? is there another way of working with ActiveMQ that would satisfy my needs?

Edit 2: MessageReceiver is no longer a spring boot bean and is instantiated every time, still the same issue.

Comment: I'm not sure about this but this might help https://activemq.apache.org/multiple-consumers-on-a-queue

Comment: so you want the message listener to consume-and-process messages concurrently? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051318/multithreaded-jms-receiving-in-spring in the question it has mentioned how to configure it (though the question is about something different)

Comment: @fctmolina okay that's useful info. So if I have 3 separate sessions/threads subscribing to the same topic I can receive a total of 3 messages at once. 

It partly solves the issue but I was hoping that I would be able to receive the message and _handle_ it in a separate session. Therefor I am not limited to the amount of sessions I create at first and I can then exceed that threshold at certain times. Looks like I need to do some research but it's a good starting point. Thanks

Comment: @AdrianShum thanks for the link, looks promising. I will need to brush on my Java skills in order the complete this haha. I'll update on my progress but might take some time.