# JMS-- MDB Scaling using concurrentConsumers

Tags: spring, jms, websphere

We are using JMS Queues in our application , As load got increased the queues are bit slow now , We want to scale the MDB listener using concurrentConsumers option of DefaultMessageListenerContainer.
The value we set is 5, but still the listener is not creating any new thread to do this. It is still sequential. I read that Prefetch option should be modified , but i dont find any option in Websphere to set this value.

We are using normal JMS Queues , how can i scale this such that the message consumption is fast in listener

Comment: looks like duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088814/how-can-i-handle-multiple-messages-concurrently-from-a-jms-topic-not-queue-wit

Comment: Thanks Scott, I tried using concurrentConsumers option, but the problem is still the Listener processes the records in the queue sequentially.Can you help

Comment: would need to see more code, but obviously it should work and people have, so likely something in your implementation.  All sorts of unknowns that I can only speculate on: what's your provider, are you using transactions (local or other), have you debugged through to make sure there's nothing else happening at the time, etc., etc.  I haven't tried anything like this in WebSphere for a while, but fairly certain that something this fundamental would work in any container....edit your initial question with more details and maybe I or someone else can see something missing in your implementation.