# Inject a new instance of an object into each request handler

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, autowired

I have a lot of Spring RestControllers with methods annotated with `RequestMapping`. I now would like to inject a custom object into these `RequestMapping` methods, and create an custom instance for each request.

I would like to write something like the following:

```
@RequestMapping("/search")
public SomeReturnObject foobar(@RequestParam("query") String query, MyRequestFoo foo) {
   // ...
}
```

Now I would like to create a mechanism, where each call to that method (i.e. each request) get a new instance of `MyRequestFoo` created and injected into the method. If this would work better with an parameter annotation instead of injecting by type, that would also be okay (e.g. `@MyRequestInject MyRequestFoo foo`).

I need to know if I can create now a method that creates a new instance of `MyRequestFoo` especially for that request, like the following:

```
public MyRequestFoo createRequestInstanceSomehow(HttpServletRequest request) {
   // extract some values from the HttpServletRequest and create a
   // new MyRequestFoo instance from that and return it
}
```

Is this possible by any means to create such a mechanism, so that I can inject custom per request objects into my request handling methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring MVC has a arguments resolver construct that directly supports your request. Every handler method annotated with *@RequestMapping* will be subject to argument resolving, where the framework scans through the handler arguments, checks the type and instantiates an appropriate object. That is the mechanism behind injecting request, model and a number of other types, just by declaring the object in the handler's method signature.

You can write a custom argument resolver to have the custom types resolved and available in the method. The procedure is simple three step process

1. Make a POJO class, in your case *MyRequestFoo*
2. Make a resolver, e.g.

   ```
     public class MyRequestFooResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

           @Override
           public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {

               return parameter.getParameterType().equals(MyRequestFoo.class);
           }

           @Override
           public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, 
                                         ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
                                         NativeWebRequest webRequest, 
                                         WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory)
           throws Exception {

               return new MyRequestFoo();
           }
       }
   ```

3.Register a resolver

```
 <mvc:annotation-driven>
     <mvc:argument-resolvers>
         <bean class="your.package.MyRequestFooResolver "></bean>  
     </mvc:argument-resolvers>
 </mvc:annotation-driven>
```

or in java config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void addArgumentResolvers(List< Handlermethodargumentresolver > argumentResolvers) {
        MyRequestFooResolver myRequestFooResolver = new MyRequestFooResolver ();
        argumentResolvers.add(myRequestFooResolver );
  }
}
```

Than you use it just by adding the type as a handler method argument

```
@RequestMapping("/search")
public SomeReturnObject search(MyRequestFoo foo) {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: I've also posted an answer now that works. Could you perhaps elaborate what is more clean and a "better" approach from your (or springs) perspective?

Comment: I've seen the discussion and posted an answer anyways as an alternative, because custom argument resolving is a concept directly supporting your requirement. I would restrain from debating on whats better, but this is the approach I would use.

Answer (score 2):

What about putting an instance variable of type MyRequestFoo on the Controller class and Autowire it changing the default scope from "Singleton" to "Request" on the Bean definition?

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20873404/is-spring-autowired-not-meant-for-non-singleton-containers) link or the Spring reference sheet!

Comment: But that would require the whole controller to be generated new for each request? Generating controllers new for each request doesn't seem like something that is meant to be done in Spring. Also I still would need to access the HttpServletRequest when creating the Autowired instance, how would I do that?

Comment: I believe he's suggesting changing the scope of the *dependency*, not that of the controller.

Comment: @chrylis unfortunately you cannot autowire request scopes beans into an instance variable inside a non request scopes bean (in this case the controller).

Comment: Do you have a citation for that? Spring does that all the time for particular beans (such as a persistence or security context).

Comment: @chrylis `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.` when it tries to create the instance of the controller.

Comment: Okay, you're talking specifically about injecting the `HttpServletRequest` into the dependency.

Comment: @chrylis No, I just tried to autowire a request scoped (but otherwise completely empty) bean to a `@RestController` and that is what happened. The stripped down example: http://pastebin.com/5pux7Cu9

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, that does what I was trying to do.

Just create the `MyRequestFoo` as a bean with scope "request" and you can access the current request via the `RequestContextHolder`:

```
@Component
@Scope("request")
public class MyRequestFoo {
   private final HttpServletRequest request;

   public MyRequestFoo() {
      request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
   }

   // do whatever you want with the request

}
```

And now i can just inject a new instance of this by its type into any request handler method:

```
@RequestMapping("/search")
public SomeReturnObject search(MyRequestFoo foo) {
   // ...
}
```

And Spring will automatically take care of instantiating a new instance.

It does not work to autowire `MyRequestFoo` as an instance variable, since you cannot autowire request scoped beans into non request scoped beans.

Comment: Magic dependency grabbing like this through static methods is a fragile pattern. In particular, it's extremely difficult to test.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to pass in request-specific information to your bean, I recommend instead injecting a builder bean into your controller and calling `builder.build(request)` from your method to create the new per-request instance.

Comment: I wanted to avoid having to inject HttpServletRequest into each request handler to then write the same builder line into each request handling method, since I need it for ALL handlers. Though it would work of course.